# How to remove or convert non UTF 8 / UTF-8 characters from a MySql column

Tags: mysql, utf-8, casting

I have a table on MySql 5 DB. The table contains data that is not a valid UTF-8 / UTF8.

The data type of the field is `LONGTEXT`.

Here is an example for this type of data:

```
receiver?àùs
```

I tried to convert and change the character set in many ways:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;

ALTER TABLE Table1 convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE Table1 CHANGE `col1` `col1` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

After I altered the table I tried to re-load it from another table that consists that data but it doesn't change... it keeps look like "receiver?àùs" instead of UTF 8 characters.

How can I convert it?

Comment: All the characters in the column are already encoded as UTF-8. This is a problem with how the data has been inserted into the table, the data that is already in the table is usually unsalvageable, especially so when you have `?` characters which implies information loss. When you are inserting data into a table, you need the physical bytes to be encoded in the same encoding as you are claiming to mysql. The claimed encoding is the Connection Encoding. And the physical encoding depends. If you are using PHP, the drivers don't enforce any physical encoding.

Comment: I used mb_convert_encoding in php before push the data to DB. That works like charm for me

Comment: I don't mind losing the non UTF-8 data. I just need to find a way to convert it to UTF-8 inside MySql. Later I'm exporting it and when I'm trying to import it to a 3rd side program the problems starts. I guess I can do something with php but I rather avoid it, I have 1,000,000+ records.

Comment: @cjg you can just declare the connection encoding correctly and you don't have to do that...

Comment: i was fetching the data from csv files, where i could not control the user's file encoding.

Comment: @cjg if you didn't know what encoding the files are in, how can you convert them? Conversion requires decoding (the `$from` part) and you cannot decode correctly if you don't know what encoding to use in decoding. :P

Comment: @Esailija actually, it has screwed up my data pretty much. From nowhere out of one file, we had UTF-16 file and i was doing json_encode(which doesnt support UTF-16) in php. Anyways, i can get the file type from finfo_file() or file Linux command

Answer (score 7):

This solved my problem:

```
select convert(binary convert(`Table1`.`col1` using latin1) using utf8) 
FROM `Table1`
```

Later on I've updated the table - I lost some data but I didn't mind. Most of it stayed.

Update query will be as follows:

```
Update Table1 
Set col1 = convert(binary convert(col1 using latin1) using utf8)
```

Comment: This worked for me as well when nested deep in an orm (propel 2).